# codeigniter 4 filters with except

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently experimenting with Codeigniter 4 Filter, for an admin section.

On $filters am I able to except a function like this:

```
public $filters = [
    'authenticate' => [
        'before' => [
            'admin/*',
        ],
        'except' => [
            'admin/verify'
        ],
    ],
];
```

So it basically add filter 'authenticate' to every admin controller except the verify one.

Doesn't seem to work.

Also wanted to use arguments on this $filters var like this:

```
public $filters = [
    'authenticate:admin' => [
```

Which also fail to work.

Am i able to make it work on Routes, but then I need to specify all the controllers functions for the filter to work. Also arguments work on the Routes.

Thanks

Comment: Found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

The [docs](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html#globals) mention this very badly positioned:

> Any place you can use a URI in the filter settings, you can use a regular expression or, like in this example, use an asterisk for a wildcard that will match all characters after that.

So you can just use a normal regular expression to achieve your goal. For example if you want all routes for `user/*` pass the `authentication` filter, BUT not `user/settings`, this is the way to go:

```
public $filters = [
    "authentication" => [
        "before" => [
            "/user\/(?!settings)/",
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: This doesn't work, don't think codeigniter 4 supports negative lookaheads like that.